# How to add session management in login page?

Tags: android, session, navigation-drawer

Hello I am following this tutorial to add session in my app http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

but my app is little bit different,in my application i have login page with edittext as per this tutorial but i have given logout option in my navigation drawer,so i am trying to add session,but its not allwing.

```
public class LoginPage extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private Button btn;
    private EditText user;
    private EditText pass;
    // Alert Dialog Manager
        AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

        // Session Manager Class
        SessionManager session;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    //JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    private Button btn1;
    private String userid;

    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://mywebsite.com/webservice/applogin";

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "status";
    private static final String TAG_LOGIN = "login";
    private static String TAG_USERID="user_login_id";
    private static final String TAG_SESSION="session";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_page);

        // Session Manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        user=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.loginmailid);
        pass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.loginpwd);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Login Status: " + session.isLoggedIn(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
        btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnreg);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.login:
            new AttemptLogin().execute();
            session.createLoginSession("Android Hive", "anroidhive@gmail.com");
            break;
        case R.id.btnreg:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, RegistrationForm.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        default:
                break;
        }

    }

class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginPage.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Login..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String...args) {
            //Check for success tag
            //int success;
            Looper.prepare();
            String username = user.getText().toString();
            String password = pass.getText().toString();
             try {
                 //Building Parameters

                 //http://gujjumatch.com/webservice/applogin?email=chirag9151@gmail.com&password=123456&version=apps
                 List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", username));
                 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
                 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("version", "apps"));

                 Log.d("request!", "starting");
                 // getting product details by making HTTP request
                 JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest (
                     LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

                 //check your log for json response
                 Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                 JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(json.toString());
                 final String msg = jobj.getString("msg");
                 TAG_USERID = jobj.getString("user_login_id");
                 System.out.println("MSG : " + msg);

                 runOnUiThread(new  Runnable() 
                 {
                    @Override
                    public void run() 
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } 
                });
                 return json.getString(TAG_SUCCESS);

                 //http://gujjumatch.com/login?version=apps&email=GM847903@param.in&password=123456
                 //JSONArray arr = json.getJSONArray("login");

                //System.out.println(arr.toString());
                //JSONObject arr1  = new JSONObject(json);
                //String ss=arr1.getString("status");
                //System.out.println(ss);
                //System.out.println(arr1.getString("status"));
                 //String date = jObj.getString("status");



             }catch (JSONException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
             return null;
        }

        // After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            //dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();
             if(file_url.equals("success")) {

                    // Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                     Intent i = new Intent(LoginPage.this, MainActivity.class);
                     Bundle b=new Bundle();
                     i.putExtra("id", TAG_USERID);
                     startActivity(i);

                 }else{
                     //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }
    }}
```

and i am using navigation drawer from this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: user shared prefrences to store either you user is login or not, and his/her basic info. You can read more here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score -1):

I made some modifications on your code and i got this code below it work fine to me

Code for LoginActivity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

ProgressDialog pDialog;

SharedPreferences settings;

// constant for user preference
public static final String LOGN_PREF = "LoginPrefs";


private Button btnLog;

CheckBox checkBox;

private EditText etUSerName;

private EditText etPasswd;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    etUSerName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
    etPasswd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
    btnLog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonEntrar);
    checkBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

    // Recovering user info
    settings = getSharedPreferences(LOGN_PREF, 0);

    // Checking if has user info recorded
    if(settings.getString("USERNAME", "")!=null && settings.getString("PASWORD", "")!=null) {
        etUSerName.setText(settings.getString("USERNAME", ""));
        etPasswd.setText(settings.getString("PASWORD", ""));
    }

}

//Method to login
public void login(View v){

    if(v.getId()==R.id.buttonLogin){

        /**
          *Calling your AsyncTask passing username and Password as parameters
          */
        new AttemptLogin().execute(new String[]{etUSerName.getText().toString(), etPasswd.getText().toString()});
    }
}
/**Save user info when checkbox is checked*/
public void itemClicked(View v) {

    if(checkBox.isChecked()){
        // Calling StartSession method
        startSession();
    }
}
//Method to save info during user session
public void startSession(){
    //settings = getSharedPreferences(LOGN_PREF, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("USERNAME", etUSerName.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("PASWORD", etPasswd.getText().toString());

    editor.commit();

}

class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    boolean failure = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Login..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String...args) {
        //Check for success tag
        //int success;
        Looper.prepare();

       try {
            //Building Parameters

            //http://gujjumatch.com/webservice/applogin?email=chirag9151@gmail.com&password=123456&version=apps
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", args[0]));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", args[1]));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("version", "apps"));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");
            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest (
                    LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

            //check your log for json response
            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

            JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(json.toString());
            final String msg = jobj.getString("msg");
            TAG_USERID = jobj.getString("user_login_id");
            System.out.println("MSG : " + msg);

            runOnUiThread(new  Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            return json.getString(TAG_SUCCESS);

            //http://gujjumatch.com/login?version=apps&email=GM847903@param.in&password=123456
            //JSONArray arr = json.getJSONArray("login");

            //System.out.println(arr.toString());
            //JSONObject arr1  = new JSONObject(json);
            //String ss=arr1.getString("status");
            //System.out.println(ss);
            //System.out.println(arr1.getString("status"));
            //String date = jObj.getString("status");



        }catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    // After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        //dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();

        if(file_url.equals("success")) {

            /** In case the user dont check remember option*/
            if(!checkBox.isChecked()){
                startSession();
            }

            // Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            Bundle b=new Bundle();
            /**i.putExtra("id", TAG_USERID);*/
            startActivity(i);

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }}
}
```

LoginLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".LoginActivity">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"

    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="Name"

        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editTextUserName" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="senha"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp">

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lembra-me"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:checked="false"
            android:onClick="itemClicked"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="164dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Entrar"
            android:onClick="login"
            android:id="@+id/buttonLogin" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Registre-se"
            android:onClick="Registre_se"
            android:id="@+id/buttonRegistre_se" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#0099cc"

            android:id="@+id/textViewProject"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout><![CDATA[





    Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />


]]>
</LinearLayout>
```

And below is my mainActivity code, just adapt this code to you mainActivity. You also can use the drawerLayout that you find on this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/).

MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

//Constant to get user info by shared preferences
SharedPreferences settings;

public static final String LOGN_PREF = "LoginPrefs";
// Field to setup drawerlayout
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
private String[] navMenuTitles;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerlayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;

public void onCreate(Bundle ic){
    super.onCreate(ic);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainlayout);

    settings = getSharedPreferences(LOGN_PREF, 0);

    //setting-up drawer menu
    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    List<DrawerPrincipalIten> it = createItens();
    ArrayAdapter<?> ad = new DrawerPrincipalAdapter(this, R.layout.tela_principal_item_drawer, it);
    mDrawerlayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer_principal);

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(ad);

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //  Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(position));
            selectItem(position);
        }
    });

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerlayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
    ){
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            //calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            //calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerlayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (ic == null) {

    }

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

}


public List<DrawerPrincipalIten> createItens(){

    String nome = settings.getString("USERNAME", "");

    List l = new ArrayList();



    l.add( new DrawerPrincipalIten(nome, R.drawable.ic_action_person, false));
    l.add( new DrawerPrincipalIten("Settings",R.drawable.ic_action_settings, false));
    l.add( new DrawerPrincipalIten("Upload",R.drawable.ic_action_upload, false));
    l.add( new DrawerPrincipalIten("Download",R.drawable.ic_action_download, false));
    l.add( new DrawerPrincipalIten("Logout",R.drawable.ic_sair, false));

    return l;
}

    /*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#onPostCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 * Metodos para tratamento do botão toggle (Icone da App) para abrir menu lateral
 */
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
    // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;

    }

    // Handle your other action bar items...
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


private void selectItem(int position) {
    // Create a new fragment and specify the planet to show based on position
    switch(position){
        case 0 :

            break;
        case 1 :

            break;
        case 2:

            break;
        case 3:

            break;
        case 4:
            // Open a dialog to ask if user want go out
            logOffDialog();
            break;
    }
}

public void logOffDialog(){

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_sair);
    alert.setTitle("Logout");
    alert.setMessage("You realy whant go out?");

    alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            /** Calling method to end user session*/
            endSection();
            finish();
        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
    alert.show();
}

public void endSection(){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
}

}
```

MainActivity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<!-- android:layout_width="240dp" -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer_principal"
    android:layout_width="290dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#111"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

i hope it helps you